# R markdown returns "\g is unrecognized escape in character" for $\geq$

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I know there are multiple threads with questions which sound similar. However, I think those mostly concern paths whereas I'm trying to label a factor.

`>=` doesn't look pretty (it's for a report) and `≥` isn't printed. So I tried latex syntax, but that doesn't work either:

```
var<-lfactor(var, levels=0:1, labels=c("Age<80", "Age $\geq$ 80"))
```

returns "\g is unrecgnized escape character".

I also tried something like

```
expression("age ">="80"))
```

and "`\u2265 80"` but none seem to work (they render completely unrelated error messages).

What am I missing? How can I print ≥ in R markdown or R labels/output in general?

Comment: Try to escape the backslash, i.e. `$\\geq 80$`.

Comment: Thank you, Ralf. I already tried that but received the same error :(

Comment: In that case please provide a [mcve].